# Oracle Performance leading wildcards search

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one select statement which joins with other table using wildcard search and performance of this statement is ridiculous

Is there any way Oralce to use index with LIKE '%string%' clause?

SQL

```
WITH x AS
        (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(a 8)  PARALLEL(b 8) ORDERED */
               a.location AS a_name, UPPER (b.name) b_name
           FROM table_a a LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b ON b.name LIKE (LOWER ('%' || a.name) || '%')
         ORDER BY a_name,  b_name)
SELECT DISTINCT a_name, b_name
  FROM x;
```

Comment: The answer is basically "no".

Comment: Why do you need a LIKE filter? Is b.name a comma-separated string of names? If so, normalizing your data model is your best hope. Otherwise you will have to accept the ridiculous performance you are seeing. (Although dbms_lob functions can help somewhat.)

Comment: The string on b.name is concatenated with few other strings on both leading and trailing and I need an another column from b for my data manipulation. This is the only key which I can join these 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an Oracle Full Text Index.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately  Index type CONTEXT not installed on my dev version, I'll ask our DBA to do something.